# Android project with different modules(sharedPreferences)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Does anyone know if Android supports sharing the same sharedpreference across multiple Android Modules compiled in one project?

I have two shared preferences and currently when I try to access some data from a shared preference outside of the current module, it doesn't work and creates a new sharedPrefence instead

example

Module one:

```
 mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Module Two:

```
 mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It creates two preference files instead of one where both modules can share the data

Answer (score 4):

You can create a common **`:core`** module and add all your dependencies in that module.

Implement **`:core`** module in all your other modules.

Place you `PrefHelpers` class in **`:core`** module to access them from any module or
 you could configure sharedpreference using common package name can be obtained using `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

```
 mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

can be replaced with

```
mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You can use the mode as `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` itself.

Make sure your `BuildConfig` is from your `:core` module.

If it resolves your issue comment back.

Comment: and this `:core` module will dependent on `:app`  module to get the reference to app's context. right?

Comment: Did you manage to work with this solution? the Context is different between the two modules so I'm not sure `context.getSharedPreferences` will lead to the same location

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by setting [`Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) (deprecated in API 17), but its **highly not recommended**.
I would use `ContentProvider`, `BroadcastReceiver`, or `Service` instead to pass data between two modules, as it is suggested in the docs by the link above.

Comment: They definitely don't want it to be used:  `Starting from N, attempting to use this mode throws a SecurityException.`